# Ionic Build: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: gradle, ionic-framework

Could someone please help me?

I'm trying to build my ionic app and I'm getting the following error:

Versions:

```
node: v10.24.1 
npm: 6.14.12 
java: Corretto-8.392.08.1 
Gradle: 8.5
cordova@10.0.0 
ionic@5.4.16
```

commands:

npx ionic cordova platform remove android

npx ionic cordova platform add android

npx ionic cordova build --debug android

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:11.0.4.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.0
   > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:11.0.4.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:19.0.0
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:11.0.4.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:19.0.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
Command failed with exit code 1: /home/lucas/projects/my-app/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /home/lucas/projects/my-app/platforms/android/build.gradle
Error: Command failed with exit code 1: /home/lucas/projects/my-app/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /home/lucas/projects/my-app/platforms/android/build.gradle
    at makeError (/home/lucas/projects/my-app/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/execa/lib/error.js:59:11)
    at handlePromise (/home/lucas/projects/my-app/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/execa/index.js:114:26)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
        
        cordova build android --debug --verbose exited with exit code 1.
        
        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: 'process.exit' received +0ms
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: running 2 functions +1ms
  ionic:utils-process processExit: exiting (exit code: 1) +39ms
```

Comment: try updating your java.

Comment: It says there's an issue with on of your plugins: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging. Either remove or update it and try o build.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a plugin:

> Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:11.0.4.

make sure this is installed since it's required by some other plugins you use.